# deleting binary data from Core Data iOS 8

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data, ios8, binary-data

I have an app that allows users to download images from a website. (Toy Collector Checklist 2 - https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/toy-collector-checklist-2/id919363870?mt=8)

The user could theoretically download thousands of images, creating quite a large usage hog. I'm trying to add a "Delete All Images" so a user can flush out the images without deleting the app.

The code seems to work. The images are no longer visible when the button is pressed, and the core data value returns "nil" when I check it - but when I go to my usage settings the space doesn't appear to be freed up. I'm using what I would consider pretty standard fetch and update code:

```
CoreDataHelper *cdh =
[(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] cdh];

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                               entityForName:@"Item"
                               inManagedObjectContext:cdh.context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
//   [fetchRequest setPredicate:nil];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"photo != nil OR photoAlt != nil OR photoCam != nil"]];
[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:500];
NSManagedObject *removePhotoFromObject;
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *results = [cdh.context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
for (removePhotoFromObject in results) {
    [removePhotoFromObject setValue:nil forKey:@"photoCam"];
    [removePhotoFromObject setValue:nil forKey:@"photo"];
    [removePhotoFromObject setValue:nil forKey:@"photoAlt"];
    [removePhotoFromObject setValue:nil forKey:@"thumbnail"];



}
[cdh backgroundSaveContext];
```

That sets the value of the possible photo locations to nil. If I run the same code again, it doesn't add them into the array (because their values are now nil), so I know that part is working. And the images and thumbnails are removed. But the data usage doesn't change when I check in the Settings tab.

Something that may be mucking up the workings:

Item is an entity.
photo, photoAlt, and photoCam are ALSO each entities, with a "To One" relationship with Item

They are all attributed as "Binary Data" in the model.

Any thoughts and suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I have looked on these forums, as well as the larger internets, but have so far been unable to find a solution.

Zack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you are setting the relationship to nil, you are not deleting the associated objects.  So I suspect they are still in your database.  Try using the following instead:

```
NSArray *results = [cdh.context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
for (removePhotoFromObject in results) {
    if (removePhotoFromObject.photoCam) [cdh.context deleteObject:removePhotoFromObject.photoCam];
    if (removePhotoFromObject.photo) [cdh.context deleteObject:removePhotoFromObject.photo];
    if (removePhotoFromObject.photoAlt) [cdh.context deleteObject:removePhotoFromObject.photoAlt];
    if (removePhotoFromObject.thumbnail) [cdh.context deleteObject:removePhotoFromObject.thumbnail];
}
```

This should delete the objects from your database (when you save the context), though note that this might not result in an immediate reduction in the storage used.  From the [CoreData Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdPersistentStores.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002875-SW13):

> Simply deleting a record from a SQLite store does not necessarily result in a reduction in the size of the file. If enough items are removed to free up a page in the database file, SQLite’s automatic database vacuuming will reduce the size of the file as it rearranges the data to remove that page. Similarly, the file size may be reduced if you remove an item that itself occupies multiple pages (such as a thumbnail image).

Comment: I think that was it! I had to make one other modification - instead of NSManagedObject *removePhotoFromObject I used Item *removePhotoFromObject since Item is my custom NSManagedObject and that is the only way I could get the '.' notation to work properly. Thanks for the tip!